# (CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY) TriggerName: execution of AfterInsert

Tags: apex, trigger, managed-package, process-builder

We are trying to create a record belongs to a custom object[related to a managed package] through process builder. This object has got an active trigger which also got from the managed package. While inserting the record through process builder the insertion is getting failed by throwing below error.

```
An error occurred at element myRule_1_A1 (FlowRecordCreate).
INSERT --- INSERT FAILED --- ERRORS : (CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY) ObjectTrigger__c: execution of AfterInsert
```

This flow is working perfectly in dev environment, we have deployed the same in another sandbox , where we are facing this issue on record creation. We checked all permission's to this profile, and everything looks normal and same as the dev environment. Apart from permission issues will there be any other factors leading to this issue??

Comment: do you have same trigger in dev org. Also your error message looks incomplete.

Comment: @TusharSharma yes the same trigger is available in dev org, I have added the proper error message now in post, I observed the trace of execution in the apex alert email on failure, that gave only this above error.

Answer (score 0):

**CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY** error is generally due to trigger going in recursion .

You may want to work with the package vendor to identify the cause for the recursion and fix it .

Looks like the combination of process builder update + trigger causes this scenario and also the scenario might be reproducible for specific dataset .

Comment: thanks for the point, we will do the same. But still confused with same data set also we are not able to reproduce this in other instance. As you said seems to be this problem here is coming with the combination of Process Builder + trigger, when we try to create the same record through apex for testing the records are getting created with no error.

Comment: The debug logs for both the scenarios should tell you the difference and help you analyze more .Without looking into code it would be shooting in the dark